# Spring MVC can't handle 404 from Resource Handler?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC 4.3.11.RELEASE and have a vanilla resource handler for static resources.  It's working fine - for resources that exist.  However if not, it appears to return a 404 to the DispatcherServlet which is happy with that response since it found a handler.  I've got ControllerAdvice for NoHandlerFoundException which works fine for controllers but isn't meant to handle this case.  So Spring MVC punts completely and I get the nasty Tomcat 404 response.  I can find no way to configure handling for this case so I can return a proper response.

With TRACE enabled for Spring, you see the following for such a request:

```
2018-03-15T14:22:05,361 TRACE [] DispatcherServlet          - Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@597aa896
2018-03-15T14:22:05,361 DEBUG [] DispatcherServlet          - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/creditcard/static/doh]
2018-03-15T14:22:05,361 TRACE [] DispatcherServlet          - Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping@4b720a14] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
2018-03-15T14:22:05,361 DEBUG [] questMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /static/doh
2018-03-15T14:22:05,364 DEBUG [] questMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/static/doh]
2018-03-15T14:22:05,364 TRACE [] DispatcherServlet          - Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping@67db7dde] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
2018-03-15T14:22:05,364 TRACE [] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping  - No handler mapping found for [/static/doh]
2018-03-15T14:22:05,364 TRACE [] DispatcherServlet          - Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping@4698270f] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
2018-03-15T14:22:05,364 DEBUG [] SimpleUrlHandlerMapping    - Matching patterns for request [/static/doh] are [/static//**]
2018-03-15T14:22:05,364 DEBUG [] SimpleUrlHandlerMapping    - URI Template variables for request [/static/doh] are {}
2018-03-15T14:22:05,364 DEBUG [] SimpleUrlHandlerMapping    - Mapping [/static/doh] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/static//]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@20537c7e]]] and 1 interceptor
2018-03-15T14:22:05,364 TRACE [] DispatcherServlet          - Testing handler adapter [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter@442b38d3]
2018-03-15T14:22:05,364 TRACE [] DispatcherServlet          - Testing handler adapter [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter@3128c8a7]
2018-03-15T14:22:05,364 DEBUG [] DispatcherServlet          - Last-Modified value for [/creditcard/static/doh] is: -1
2018-03-15T14:22:05,364 TRACE [] ResourceHttpRequestHandler - Applying "invalid path" checks to path: doh
2018-03-15T14:22:05,364 TRACE [] PathResourceResolver       - Resolving resource for request path "doh"
2018-03-15T14:22:05,364 TRACE [] PathResourceResolver       - Checking location: ServletContext resource [/static//]
2018-03-15T14:22:05,364 TRACE [] PathResourceResolver       - No match for location: ServletContext resource [/static//]
2018-03-15T14:22:05,364 TRACE [] ResourceHttpRequestHandler - No matching resource found - returning 404
2018-03-15T14:22:05,364 DEBUG [] DispatcherServlet          - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2018-03-15T14:22:05,364 TRACE [] DispatcherServlet          - Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@597aa896
2018-03-15T14:22:05,364 DEBUG [] DispatcherServlet          - Successfully completed request
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Did you solve this ? I'm hitting the same issue currently...

Comment: An easy way to solve this is to disable the default resource handling, which adds mappings for /webjars/** and /** in your application.properties:
`spring.resources.add-mappings=false`
But obviously you can't always do that (in my case I need it for Swagger)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. My solution as follows:

- spring.resources.add-mappings=false (either in yaml or application.properties)
- in Config of WebMvcConfigurer 'addResourceHandlers' method add all your mappings, e.g.:

  ```
  @Configuration
  public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
      @Override
      public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
          registry.addResourceHandler("/home.html**")
                  .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/views/home/");
      }

      @Override
      public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
                DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
          // DO not enable this ! 
          // configurer.enable();
          // Remove this method! 
      }
  }
  ```
- must remove default servlet handler, as it will try to handle and return with status 404, but never throws the NoHandlerFoundException
- add GlobalExceptionHandler Controller advice:

  ```
  @ControllerAdvice
  public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
      @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
      public String handleNotFoundError(Exception ex) {
          return "redirect:/your404page";
      }
  }
  ```

Hope this helps! For me it works perfectly!

Comment: You saved me! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The mrkurtan answer only works for spring-boot, as `spring.resources.add-mappings=false` is a spring-boot configuration

so re-writing required configuration to through NoHandlerFoundException and handle it.

1. Create a class `GlobalExceptionHandler` annotated with `@ControllerAdvice`

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler 
{
    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    public String handleNotFoundError(Exception ex) 
    {
        return "redirect:/yourCustom404page";
    }
}
```

2. By default, when a page/resource does not exist the servlet container will throw a default 404 page. If you want a custom 404 response then you need to tell `DispatcherServlet` to throw the exception if no handler is found. We can do this by setting the `throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound` servlet initialization parameter to `true`

In spring-mvc java based configuration is

```
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer
{
    ...

    @Override
    protected DispatcherServlet createDispatcherServlet(WebApplicationContext servletAppContext) 
    {
        final DispatcherServlet servlet = (DispatcherServlet) super.createDispatcherServlet(servletAppContext);
        servlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
        return servlet;
    }

}
```

if xml based configuration, initialize your dispatcher servlet like this

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```